# Get list of unreviewed changeset

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I need to find list of changesets that were not reviewed. The perfect case is command line tool but any GUI is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your requirement can't be achieved by any commands through command line. Cause there are not any related tags or propertys about a changest to distinguish whether this changeset has been reviewed or not.

All you can do in GUI, check My work → Code Reviews →  Recently Closed, you will get the result which changests have been reviewed.
[image]

In addition, this is also a great User Voice, you can submmit it in the below link http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio